# awk join script making me absolutely batty

Tags: awk

I'm trying to use awk to lookup values from first CSV file “map.txt” with two columns (col1 = key, col2 = value) and then to use col 3 of second file “textile.txt” as key when replacing same col3 with col2 of file 1.

Example Files:

**map.txt**

```
a,apple
b,pear
c,peeps
d,gingersnaps
e,goop
```

**textfile.txt**

```
1,This is one,a
2,This is two,b
3,This is three,c
4,This is four,d
5,This is five,e
```

And the desired output:

```
1,This is one,apple
2,This is two,pear
3,This is three,peeps
4,This is four,gingersnaps
5,This is five,goop
```

Results:
I have made this work with the test files, but when the actual files are used, though the keys are properly read into the array, only one line, the last one, if more than one line is present, is actually correctly substituted.

Various versions of awk script have been attempted—-current version is verbose and using getline for debugging:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}

(FNR==NR){
fname=ARGV[ARGC-2];
print fname;
do
{getline < fname;
lookup[$1]=$2;
print $1 " = " $2;
}
while (getline);
close(fname)
fname=ARGV[ARGC-1];
}

(fname==ARGV[ARGC-1]){
print fname;
do
{getline < ARGV[ARGC-1];
$3=lookup[$3];
print $3 " " $0;
}
while (getline);
next;
}
```

For what it's worth, this is on OSX.

Comment: Can you show us the command line you use to invoke your awk script?

Comment: If you have access to join: `join -t , -1 1 -2 3 -o 2.1,2.2,1.2 map.txt textfile.txt`

Comment: There are occasions to use `getline`, but not many of them.

Comment: Sounds like your real data has DOS line endings or some other text file integrity problem (on OSX it's even possible to have legacy MacOS line endings, although I don't think you can run software which produces them any longer). See the [Stack Overflow `bash` tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) for some troubleshooting tips.

Comment: tripleee--you sir or madam are a Saint. Somehow during the export process the first file ended up with proper UNIX LFs, but the second file ended up with Windows CRLFs. I knew it was a file diff, but could not pin it down becasue in a Mac environment using TextMate or TextWrangler I did not look at the very bottom to see the EOLs were not consistent. Thanks so much for your keen observation.

Comment: If it's possible for this to happen then edit your question to show the expected output for cases where a key value from each file is absent from the other file (e.g. map.txt contains 1 more line `g,foo` and textfile.txt contains `6,This is bar,f`). And add some white space and indentation to your code - it's surprisingly cheap and beneficial when reading it! You could even trade in all those useless trailing semi-colons for tab chars.

Answer (score 4):

I think you made it too complicated.
This seems to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    FS=OFS=","
}

NR == FNR {
    lookup[$1] = $2
}

NR != FNR {
    print $1,$2,lookup[$3]
}
```

Running this, I get:

```
# ./thing.awk map.txt textfile.txt
1,This is one,apple
2,This is two,pear
3,This is three,peeps
4,This is four,gingersnaps
5,This is five,goop
```

The first block `NR == FNR { .. }` reads the map file.  The second reads `textfile.txt` (and any additional files you put on the command line).

Comment: Agree with the 'made it too complicated' assessment — your solution is very much what is called for.

Comment: It's quite common to use `next` in the block for the first file, so you don't need the `NR != FNR` condition for the second file.

Comment: @TomFenech is correct. Use `next` in the first block and get rid of the negated condition before the second block and this is the right solution as long as the identical keys appear in both files. If they DON'T then some more work may be needed but the OP hasn't shown us how to handle that yet.

Answer (score 0):

The following script avoids the (probably small) overhead of having to test NR==FNR, and makes it easy to specify the column number of the field to be translated (here: col=3):

```
awk -F, -v col=3 -v dict=map.txt '
  BEGIN {OFS=FS; while( (getline<dict) > 0) {a[$1]=$2} }
  a[$col] {$col = a[$col]}
  { print $0 }
' textfile.txt
```

Note that if the 'key' of a line in the data file (textfile.txt) is not found in the dictionary, then the above script will print that line without alteration.  If that is not the desired behavior, the script can easily be tweaked.

Comment: `NR==FNR` is a standard pattern; I really don't see any advantage to your approach. I'm not sure why you think that reading a line using `getline` is going to be any less overhead than a simple comparison.

Comment: It wasn't about the overhead, it was about the fact that a test run with the indicated samples worked, but a run with the actual much larger data files, still one 2 col lookup file, and one 3 col file to be massaged did not--thus I went to getline to and a pile of print statements to see if it was actually reading all the lines of the target file.